# How to combine multiple .out files to a single file in Windows environment?

Tags: linux, out

I was given hundreds of files in .out format. I appreciate if you can help me find a way to combine them all in one file. I have no Linux knowledge and will prefer to work it out with Python

Comment: What do you mean by `.out` format? Are they generic text files? Binary files? What are they? Way more detail needed.

Comment: Thanks you Robin for the feedback. It is a text file stored through Linux. The text contains some special characters but they are not important. The origin of the text comes from tweets gathered by a java script.

Comment: OK, so what kind of combining do you want to do? Simple concatenation? Summarisation?

Comment: I apologize for not being specific in my question (I edited my question). I need to combine all the files to only one file so that I can convert it to a database file and bring it to the ArcMap software and do the analysis which brings up another task: converting .out to a .dbf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to concatenate the files you can use Windows [`type`](https://ss64.com/nt/type.html) command which behaves like Linux `cat`:

```
type *.out > result.dbf
```

Comment: Thank you very much Karol. It worked. I actually tried csv as well and it worked too.

Comment: Done! Thank you again